Uniformization Theorem and Non Existence of Family of Elliptic Curves over Riemann Sphere
A question concerning a statement from these notes introducing/motivating period map. On first page, left column, last sentence states:

Since $\Bbb{H}$ (=complex upper half plane) is biholomorphic to the unit disk, one finds, as a consequence of the uniformization theorem, that any nonconstant family of elliptic curves parametrized by the Riemann sphere must have at least three singular fibers.

Could somebody elaborate why this is a consequence of (Riemann's) uniformization theorem?
Some remarks: The upshotup to now was that for any family of elliptic curves parametrized by base $T$ (ie holomorphic map $f:E \to T$ such that each fibre $E_s$ ($t \in T$) is elliptic curve, the period map gives a holomorphic map $P_f: T \to \Bbb H$ to upper half plane (see in linked notes for details)
By I not understand how (at least heuristically) the uniformization theorem implies from this that in case $T:= \Bbb CP^1 \cong S^2$ (=Riemannian sphere) the family $f: E \to S^2$ have at least three singular fibres.
The period map would induce $P_f: S^2 \to \Bbb H $ where the latter as remarked by uniformization Thm is biholomorphic to complex unit disc $\Bbb D$, $P_f$ would be bounded. Thus by Liouville $P_f$ must be constant, so $f: E \to S^2$ cannot be "a family" of elliptic curves, so has somewhere singular fibres.
But why this implies that such family $f$ must have at least three singular fibers?

The period map will not send your base $S$ to the upper half-plane, unless you are working with the universal covering space of $S$ (probably, you do). Now, use the fact that the universal cover of the sphere with less than 3 punctures does not admit nonconstant holomorphic maps to the upper half-plane.

@MoisheKohan: there is a little notational conflict above; I modified the notations in order to distiguish better between an abstract base  $T$ of a family $f:E \to T$ of ell curves, vs concrete base $S^2$ the Riemann sphere.

Now, regarding your first sentence that in general for family $E \to T$ the period map not maps $T$ to $\Bbb H$, but only from $T's$ univ cover: Indeed, the linked survey not mentions this important part and its not clear if they tacitly assume the base $T$ to be already simply connected. Could you give a reference for this part in the construction of the period map? So far I understand you correctly your point is that if we start with a famly $f:E \to T$ then in order to get the induced period map we need to pass/"pullback" $f$ to universal cover of $T$ and only then the period

map can be constructed, is this the idea?

@MoisheKohan: Moreover, I also not fully understand your secound sentence: Isn't the Riemann sphere already a universal cover? (It has trivial fundamental group)

Correct, this is what I wrote in the first comment. Any textbook dealing with period maps will address this issue. This is not special to elliptic curves and applies to all Riemann surfaces, just the period domain will be different.

Yes, my comment applies to all surfaces which are punctured spheres with less than 3 punctures. One of them will not be simply connected, namely, $\mathbb C^*$.

@MoisheKohan: ah right, and its univ cover is $\Bbb C$ - which also coincides with the sphere with one point removed. And here again Liouville says that these cannot map holomorphically nonconstantly to $\Bbb H \cong \Bbb D$. Thanks!

Right...........

But, I have to say, I do not see why one needs to quote the Uniformization Theorem here, it is just elementary complex analysis.

The thing is that to define the period map (to the period domain), you have to fix a basis of the 1st integer homology group of your Riemann surface. If you have a smooth holomorphic family $X\to B$ of genus $g$ Riemann surfaces, then you can fix such a basis of homology of the fibers locally but (in general) not globally, since the fundamental group of the base of the family typically acts nontrivially on homology of the fibers. One way to eliminate this problem is to lift this family to the universal cover of $B$, $\tilde X\to \tilde B$ (a family of genus $g$ Riemann surfaces). Now, you have a global trivialization of $H_1$ of the fibers and you proceed to define the (holomorphic) period map $f: \tilde B\to {\mathcal H}_g$. If $\tilde B$ is either compact or is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$, then a holomorphic map $f$ has to be constant. In the case $g=1$ this is just Liouville's theorem. From this, it follows that every smooth holomorphic family of genus $g$ Riemann surfaces over a complex curve $B$ whose universal cover is compact or $\mathbb C$ has to be trivial. In the case when $B$ is obtained by removing $n$ points from the Riemann sphere, it means that a nontrivial family has $n\ge 3$.

one can also phrase it in terms of fibre bundles that here the neccessarity to pullback the family $f:X \to B$ of ell curves along univ cover in order to construct welldefined period map has to do with nonexistence of global section of induced fibre bundle - "frame bundle" -$f_p: F \to B$ whose fibers $F_b$ corresp to set of frames aka ordered bases of 1st homology of $X_b$.

@user267839 It amounts to the same thing I described in my answer. And elliptic curves are irrelevant here, it works for all genera.
